# i try a multiple regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I can't seem to find any python libraries that do multiple regression. The only things I find only do simple regression. I need to regress my dependent variable (y) against several independent variables (x1, x2, x3, etc.).

Can't find the error in my code:

```py
       #data['PROFIT','HI','LO'] = data.target 
        #ycenter=pd.DataFrame(np.c_[data['PROFIT'],data['HI'],data['LO']], columns=['PROFIT','HI','LO'])
        #Xcenter=pd.DataFrame(np.c_[data['ROLL'],data['DICE'],data['FREE'],data['STAKE'],data['MULT']],        columns=['ROLL','DICE','FREE','STAKE','MULT'])
       Xcenter=data['ROLL','DICE','FREE','STAKE','MULT']
       Ycenter=data['PROFIT','HI','LO'] 
   # split into 70:30 ration 
       X_traincenter, X_testcenter, y_traincenter, y_testcenter = train_test_split(Xcenter, ycenter, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0) 
# describes info about traincenter and testcenter set 
print("Number transactions X_traincenter dataset: ", X_traincenter.shape) 
print("Number transactions y_traincenter dataset: ", y_traincenter.shape) 
print("Number transactions X_testcenter dataset: ", X_testcenter.shape) 
print("Number transactions y_testcenter dataset: ", y_testcenter.shape)

print("Before OverSampling, counts of positive profitcenter: {}".format(sum(y_traincenter > 0))) 
print("Before OverSampling, counts of negative profitcenter: {} \n".format(sum(y_traincenter < 0))) 
 #Initialize the linear model center
regcenter = LinearRegression()

 #Train the model with our training datacenter
regcenter.fit(X_traincenter,y_traincenter)

 #Print the coeffiscients/weights for each feature/column of our model
print(regcenter.coef_) #f(x,a) = mx + da + b =y

 #Print the predictions on our test datacenter
y_predcenter = regcenter.predict(X_testcenter)
print(y_predcenter)

 #Print the actual values center
print(y_testcenter)

 #Check the model performance/accuracy using Mean Squared Error (MSE)
print(np.mean((y_predcenter - y_testcenter)**2))

 #Check the model performance/accuracy using Mean Squared Error (MSE) and sklearn.metrics
print(mean_squared_error(y_testcenter,y_predcenter))
 #check the predictions against the actual values by using the RMSE and R-2 metrics
test_setcenter_rmse = (np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_testcenter, y_predcenter)))
print('test_setcenter_rmse = ',test_setcenter_rmse)
test_setcenter_r2 = r2_score(y_testcenter, y_predcenter)
print('test_setcenter_r2 = ',test_setcenter_r2)
```

How would I regress these in python, to get the linear regression formula:

```
Y(x3,x5) = a1x1 + a2x2 + a3x4 + a4x6 + a5x7 + a6x8 + +a7x9 + c
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Python can perform multiple regression as well as polynomial regression.

But if you want you can perform gradient descent-
Gradient Descent:  [here](https://github.com/shantanutheone/Machine-Learning-Codes-in-Python/blob/master/Linear%20Regression/Multi-Feature%20Linear%20Regression.py)


And also you can use normal equation method to perform multiple regression-

 
Normal Equation:  [here](https://github.com/shantanutheone/Machine-Learning-Codes-in-Python/blob/master/Linear%20Regression/Normal%20Equation.py)


But if you don't want to write code for normal equation or gradient descent just use python's sklearn library for it and it works for both single feature and multiple features.

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split` 
 
`from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression`   
`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=1)` 
`reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()`

`reg.fit(X_train, y_train)`

`reg.predict(X_test)`